# android get different id on listview item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a little problem sending the right id to another activity as extra.I'm getting id from database which I'm sending to the new activity so I can get the right data. But the problem is that my code is sending only the last id,which is on arraylist. How can I fix that?

Here is the code I'm using :

```
for(cursorTitle.move(0); cursorTitle.moveToNext(); cursorTitle.isAfterLast()) {

     if (vf != null) {
        vf.removeAllViews();
     }                                      

     text = cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("title"));
     cardsCount = cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("cardsCount"));
     collId = Integer.parseInt(cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
     Log.i("CollID","Collection ID : "+collId);
     b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/7073d92dce10884554d7e047f1c51cb6.jpg", null); 
     array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     array.add(collId);
     vf = new ViewFlipper(MyCollectionList.this);
     myListView = new ListView(MyCollectionList.this);                                      

     hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     hm.put(IMAGE, b);
     hm.put(TITLE, text);
     hm.put(CARDS_COUNT, cardsCount +" Stampii");
     items.add(hm);

     final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyCollectionList.this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
     new String[]{TITLE, CARDS_COUNT, IMAGE}, new int[]{ R.id.main_name, R.id.main_info, R.id.main_img});
     myListView.setAdapter(adapter); 

     myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
         {
          Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), MyCollectionId.class);
          previewMessage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
          previewMessage.putExtra("collection_id", array.get(position));
          parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", previewMessage);
         }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new ArrayList in each iteration and then assigning only a single value to it. I don't think that is what you intended. You should instantiate the ArrayList outside of your loop. You'll also want to move all of your other one-time initialization code (ListView, SimpleAdapter, etc.) out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What i got is,you need to populate a listview with the records you get in cursor.You are populating your listview in each iteration of for loop and that is what causes problem.i think,following should work for you. (Required changes for varibles should be made accordingly.)

Try this:

```
vf = new ViewFlipper(MyCollectionList.this);
myListView = new ListView(MyCollectionList.this);
array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for(cursorTitle.move(0); cursorTitle.moveToNext(); cursorTitle.isAfterLast()) {

         if (vf != null) {
            vf.removeAllViews();
         }                                      

         text = cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("title"));
         cardsCount = cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("cardsCount"));
         collId = Integer.parseInt(cursorTitle.getString(cursorTitle.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
         Log.i("CollID","Collection ID : "+collId);
         b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/7073d92dce10884554d7e047f1c51cb6.jpg", null);              
         array.add(collId);


         hm.put(IMAGE, b);
         hm.put(TITLE, text);
         hm.put(CARDS_COUNT, cardsCount +" Stampii");
         items.add(hm);
}

    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyCollectionList.this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
         new String[]{TITLE, CARDS_COUNT, IMAGE}, new int[]{ R.id.main_name, R.id.main_info, R.id.main_img});
         myListView.setAdapter(adapter);                                    
         myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
         {
              Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), MyCollectionId.class);
              previewMessage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
              TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
              previewMessage.putExtra("collection_id", array.get(position));
              parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", previewMessage);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `array = new ArrayList<Integer>();` outside of for loop.

like,

```
  array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(cursorTitle.move(0); cursorTitle.moveToNext(); cursorTitle.isAfterLast()) {
  { 
   // your stuff

   array.add(collId);

   // your stuff
  }
```